# Deriving marginal effects in multinomial logit model

Tags: probability, statistics, derivatives

For the multinomial logit model, it holds that:
$$P[y_i=j]=\frac{\exp{\beta_{0,j} + \beta_1 x_{ij}}}{\sum_h \exp(\beta_{0,h} + \beta_1 x_{ih})}$$.

Now my book states that the marginal effect is as follows:

$$\dfrac{\partial \operatorname{P}[y_i = j]}{\partial x_{ij}} = \operatorname{P}[y_i=j](1-\operatorname{P}[y_i=j])\beta_1$$

I tried derving this but I did not find an easy way. Could anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: (Btw: Does anyone know if there is a tag for multinomial choice models? I couldn't find a related one.)

Comment: In the denominator are you sure is $x_{ij}$ and not $x_{ih}$ (to sum $1$)

Comment: @rlartiga You're right, I'll edit it. Sorry for being sloppy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross multiply the equation to obtain:
$$\operatorname{P}(y_i=j)\sum_h \exp(\beta_{0,h} + \beta_1 x_{ih})=\exp(\beta_{0,j} + \beta_1 x_{ij})$$
Then deriving with respect to $x_{ij}$ on both sides of the equality gives the following:

$$\dfrac{\partial \operatorname{P}(y_i = j)}{\partial x_{ij}}\sum_h \exp(\beta_{0,h} + \beta_1 x_{ih})+\operatorname{P}(y_i=j)\beta_1  \exp(\beta_{0,j} + \beta_1 x_{ij})= \beta_1\exp(\beta_{0,j} + \beta_1 x_{ij})$$
Now if we divide by $\sum_h \exp(\beta_{0,h} + \beta_1 x_{ih})$ we obtain:

$$\dfrac{\partial \operatorname{P}(y_i = j)}{\partial x_{ij}}+\operatorname{P}(y_i=j)\beta_1  \operatorname{P}(y_i=j)= \beta_1\operatorname{P}(y_i=j)$$

And the result is complete.

Comment: @dreamer you are welcome!

Comment: @rlatiga I suggested an edit to elaborate on a few things which took me a while to see, I hope you don´t mind. Again, thanks a lot!